# How to specify username in the command line for Fastlane?

Tags: ios, fastlane

I'm trying to pass in the apple ID to Fastlane as a command line option so all users and our build servers can use the same script.

```
MacBook-Pro-6:whisper-ios Nick$ fastlane hockeyglobal username:nlocking@whisper.sh
[18:00:44]: -------------------------------------------------
[18:00:44]: --- Step: Verifying required fastlane version ---
[18:00:44]: -------------------------------------------------
[18:00:44]: fastlane version valid
[18:00:44]: ------------------------------
[18:00:44]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[18:00:44]: ------------------------------
[18:00:44]: Driving the lane 'hockeyglobal' 
[18:00:44]: ------------------
[18:00:44]: --- Step: sigh ---
[18:00:44]: ------------------

+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+
|                   Summary for sigh 1.8.0                    |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| adhoc                               | true                  |
| skip_install                        | false                 |
| development                         | false                 |
| force                               | false                 |
| app_identifier                      | sh.whisper.whisperapp |
| team_id                             | B3NYR7PARX            |
| ignore_profiles_with_different_name | false                 |
| skip_fetch_profiles                 | false                 |
| skip_certificate_verification       | false                 |
+-------------------------------------+-----------------------+

[18:00:45]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'username'
Your Apple ID Username:
```

Maddeningly, `username:nlocking@whisper.sh` seems to go completely unnoticed by Fastlane, as does `apple_id:nlocking@whisper.sh`, `-u nlocking@whisper.sh` and everything else I've tried. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the `hockeyglobal` lane, but generally the correct syntax to pass the `username` parameter would be as follows:

```
fastlane hockeyglobal --username 'nlocking@whisper.sh'
```

E.g. for default `cert` lane this works:

```
 fastlane cert --username 'me@myemailcom'
```

or

```
 fastlane cert -u 'me@myemailcom'
```

Comment: Doesn't work for custom lanes: ```invalid option: -u```

Answer (score 2):

Try remove username, add only `app_identifier`, `apple_id` (email) and `team_id` in Appfile

Comment: `apple_id` made a job! ;)

Answer (score 2):

It will use the value of `apple_id` in your `fastlane/Appfile`. Make sure you're running the command from the folder that `fastlane/` is in.

Comment: I have apple_id value in AppFile but still asking :(

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using fastlane parameters. In your Fastfile do something like this:

```
lane :beta do |options|
  cert(username: options[:username])
  ...
end
```

(notice the `|options|` parameter above)

Then invoke fastlane like this:

```
fastlane beta username:email@example.com
```

Where email@example.com is your username.